# : type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Response>'

Tags: flutter, dart, http, testing, mockito

I am new to programming and flutter in general. I am trying to learn how to write tests for a stateful widget.

I am trying to mock a http request but keep getting this error when I ran the test:

```
══╡ EXCEPTION CAUGHT BY FLUTTER TEST FRAMEWORK ╞════════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following _TypeError was thrown running a test:
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Response>'
```

This is the test that I wrote:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_test/flutter_test.dart';
import 'package:foodbridge_project/models/listing.dart';
import 'package:foodbridge_project/screens/listings_list_screen.dart';
import 'package:foodbridge_project/widgets/listing_grid_item.dart';
import 'package:mockito/mockito.dart';

class MockStream extends Mock implements Stream<List<Listing>> {}

class MockClient extends Mock implements http.Client {}

void main() {
  late MockClient mockClient;

  setUp(() {
    mockClient = MockClient();
  });

  testWidgets('Non empty ListingsScreen - Displays listings in GridView',
      (WidgetTester tester) async {
    final mockClient = MockClient();
    final mockStream = Stream<List<Listing>>.fromIterable([
      [
        Listing(
          id: '1',
          itemName: 'itemName',
          image: 'https://example.com/data',
          mainCategory: 'mainCat',
          subCategory: 'subCategory',
          dietaryNeeds: 'dietaryNeeds',
          additionalNotes: 'additionalNotes',
          expiryDate: DateTime.now(),
          lat: 1.11,
          lng: 2.22,
          address: 'address',
          isAvailable: true,
          userId: 'userId',
          userName: 'userName',
          userPhoto: 'https://example.com/data',
          addressImageUrl: 'https://example.com/data',
          isExpired: false,
          isDonorReviewed: false,
          isRecipientReviewed: false,
          // Add other required properties as needed
        ),
        Listing(
          id: '2',
          itemName: 'itemName',
          image: 'https://example.com/data',
          mainCategory: 'mainCat',
          subCategory: 'subCategory',
          dietaryNeeds: 'dietaryNeeds',
          additionalNotes: 'additionalNotes',
          expiryDate: DateTime.now(),
          lat: 1.11,
          lng: 2.22,
          address: 'address',
          isAvailable: true,
          userId: 'userId',
          userName: 'userName',
          userPhoto: 'https://example.com/data',
          addressImageUrl: 'https://example.com/data',
          isExpired: false,
          isDonorReviewed: false,
          isRecipientReviewed: false,
          // Add other required properties as needed
        ),
      ]
    ]);

    await tester.pumpWidget(
      MaterialApp(
        home: Scaffold(
          body: ListingsScreen(
            availListings: mockStream,
            isYourListing: false,
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
    when(mockClient.get(Uri.parse('https://example.com/data')))
        .thenAnswer((_) async => http.Response('your mock response', 200));

    expect(find.byType(CircularProgressIndicator), findsOneWidget);
    await tester.pumpAndSettle();
    // Verify that the GridView is displayed
    expect(find.byKey(const Key('Gridview')), findsOneWidget);

    // Verify that the correct number of ListingGridItem widgets are present
    expect(find.byType(ListingGridItem), findsNWidgets(2));
  });
}
```

I am not sure what went wrong but the stack traces the error to

```
when(mockClient.get(Uri.parse('https://example.com/data')))
        .thenAnswer((_) async => http.Response('your mock response', 200));
```

For reference, this is the stateful widget i am trying to test:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import '../models/listing.dart';
import '../widgets/listing_grid_item.dart';

class ListingsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const ListingsScreen({
    super.key,
    required this.availListings,
    required this.isYourListing,
  });

  final Stream<List<Listing>> availListings;
  final bool isYourListing;

  @override
  State<ListingsScreen> createState() => _ListingsScreenState();
}

class _ListingsScreenState extends State<ListingsScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget buildListing(Listing listing) => ListingGridItem(
          data: listing,
          isYourListing: widget.isYourListing,
        );

    return Column(
      children: [
        StreamBuilder(
            stream: widget.availListings,
            builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
              if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(
                    child: Text(
                  'Something went wrong, ${snapshot.error}',
                  key: const Key('error message'),
                ));
              } else if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
                return const Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
              } else if (snapshot.data == null || snapshot.data!.isEmpty) {
                return const Center(
                    child: Text(
                  'No available listings',
                  style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
                  key: Key('No available listings text'),
                ));
              } else if (snapshot.hasData) {
                final allListings = snapshot.data!;

                return Expanded(
                  child: GridView(
                    key: const Key('Gridview'),
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16),
                    gridDelegate:
                        const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                      crossAxisCount: 2,
                      childAspectRatio: 0.75,
                      crossAxisSpacing: 20,
                      mainAxisSpacing: 20,
                    ),
                    children: allListings
                        .map<Widget>((listings) => buildListing(listings))
                        .toList(),
                  ),
                );
              } else {
                return const Text('Nothing to show');
              }
            })
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks

I have referred to the following links but am still unclear and unable to solve the issue:
[Mocktail: type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Response>'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69889524/mocktail-type-null-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-futureresponse)

[type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'Future<Response>' when testing mocked http client with Mocktail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67899067/type-null-is-not-a-subtype-of-type-futureresponse-when-testing-mocked-http?r=SearchResults&s=7%7C189.6106)